# jqPlot issue - 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating $.jqplot.BarRenderer.js

Tags: jquery-mobile, jqplot

I am using jquery mobile and jqplot to create a simple bar graph.

I have currently got the code for creating my bar graph in
`$( '#divForMyPage' ).live( 'pageinit',function(event){ // bar graph code }`

However I keep getting the error: `undefined` is not an object (evaluating $.jqplot.BarRenderer.js)

The code I'm using to render the bar graph is below: Any help would be most appreciated!

```
  var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1], {
              title: 'Results',
              series:[{renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer}],
              axesDefaults: {
                  tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer ,
                  tickOptions: {
                    angle: 0,
                    fontSize: '10pt'
                  }
              },
              axes: {
                xaxis: {
                  renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
                }
              }
            });
```

Comment: Why did you put square brackets around the series renderer? `series:[{renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer}]` instead of `series:{renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer}` Did you also make sure that you have first included the plugin after jqPlot:

`<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js"></script>`